# Module: 'objects-to-csv' is throwing an error when running with Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress, node-modules

module: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/objects-to-csv](https://stackoverflow.com)

I want to use this module in Cypress project.

when I am implementing this module in cypress test it throws below error.
[image]

I have test using this module in node project and it works as expected.

**Example code I am running within Cypress test.**

```js
const ObjectsToCsv = require('objects-to-csv');
describe('template spec', () => {
  
  it('objects-to-csv', () => {

    // Sample data - two columns, three rows:
    const data = [
      { code: 'CA', name: 'California' },
      { code: 'TX', name: 'Texas' },
      { code: 'NY', name: 'New York' },
    ];
    
    // If you use "await", code must be inside an asynchronous function:
    (async () => {
      const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(data);
    
      // Save to file:
      await csv.toDisk('./test.csv');
    
      // Return the CSV file as string:
      console.log(await csv.toString());
    })();
  })
})
```

**tsconfig.json:**

{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es2016",
"module": "commonjs",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"skipLibCheck": true
}
}

What I am doing wrong when running this module within Cypress project.

I am trying the simple implementation code for module within Cypress project. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/objects-to-csv](https://stackoverflow.com)

Code is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute a nodejs library in the browser.

The test functions (`it()` blocks) execute in the browser, not in nodejs, so you don't have access to the underlying filesystem objects (`fs`).

In order to write to the filesystem in Cypress, you have to create a task and call it from the test.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task

```js
// cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        async toCSV(data) {
          const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(data);
    
          // Save to file
          await csv.toDisk('./test.csv');
    
          // Return the CSV file as string:
          return await csv.toString();
        },
      })
    },
  },
})


// spec file
it('test', () => {
  const data = [
    { code: 'CA', name: 'California' },
    { code: 'TX', name: 'Texas' },
    { code: 'NY', name: 'New York' },
  ];

  cy.task('toCSV', data).then(csvString => { /* do something */ });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Cypress provides `cy.writeFile()` to write data from the browser.

Use it instead of `csv.toDisk()` when running inside the test:

```js
it('objects-to-csv', () => {

  // Sample data - two columns, three rows:
  const data = [
    { code: 'CA', name: 'California' },
    { code: 'TX', name: 'Texas' },
    { code: 'NY', name: 'New York' },
  ];

  // If you use "await", code must be inside an asynchronous function:
  (async () => {
    const csvObj = new ObjectsToCsv(data);
    const csv = await csvObj.toString()

    // Save to file:
    cy.writeFile('./test.csv', csv)

    console.log(csv);
    /*
      code,name
      CA,California
      TX,Texas
      NY,New York
    */

    // Return the CSV file as string:
    return csv
  })();
})
```

---

**Using a task does not require async/await**

The task automatically resolves a promise before returning to the test:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        toCSV(data) {
          const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(data);
          csv.toDisk('./test.csv');   
          return csv.toString();
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

```js
it('objects-to-csv', () => {
  cy.task('toCSV', data)
    .then(cy.log)
})
```

Test log:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. There's a slight improvement to the task, since Cypress resolves promises returned from a task for you.